# User Active Check

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a small script to check the database for value 0 or 1 but I can't seem to get it working, I have tried a row count but have the same issue.

```
public function is_active($id){
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT activedd FROM users WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    if($userRow == '0'){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function is then being called on all pages

```
$id = $_SESSION['session'];

if(!$user->is_active($id)){
    $user->redirect('../users/inactive.php');
}
```

Changing the value in the cell makes no difference, I only get a different result by changing

`$id = $_SESSION['session'];
if(!$user->is_active($id)){
$user->redirect('../users/inactive.php');
}`

to

`$id = $_SESSION['session'];
if($user->is_active($id)){
$user->redirect('../users/inactive.php');
}`

But even then I have the same issue, but it's the other way around.  I am trying to redirect users to an inactive page when `$userRow == 0` and allow them to continue using the website if it is 1.

Comment: Try `if($userRow['activedd'] == '0'){`. You're comparing an associative array with `0` with your current code.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I have, it doesn't I just didn't think I needed to add the entire page.

Comment: @andrewsi That got it, I didn't think I could have to specify the column as I was only calling one.  I couldn't get it to work before like this, please add as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
if($userRow == '0'){
```

You're getting an associative array back from `fetch`, and comparing it with `0` on the next line. Instead, you want to check the value for the column you've selected in your query, and compare with that:

```
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
if($userRow['activedd'] == '0'){
```